# How do I find multiple substrings from one string using regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I want to find every instance of a number, followed by a comma (no space), followed by any number of characters in a string. I was able to get a regex to find all the instances of what I was looking for, but I want to print them individually rather than all together. I'm new to regex in general, so maybe my pattern is wrong?

This is my code:

```
String test = "1 2,A 3,B 4,23";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+,.+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
while(m.find()) {
  System.out.println("found: " + m.group());
}
```

This is what it prints:

```
found: 2,A 3,B 4,23
```

This is what I want it to print:

```
found: 2,A
found: 3,B
found: 4,23
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this regex

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+,.+?(?= |$)");
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take an easier route and split by space, then ignore anything without a comma:

```
String values = test.split(' ');

for (String value : values) {
    if (value.contains(",") {
        System.out.println("found: " + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does seem easier, but I have to add some more conditions later making regex more suitable. Thank you though!

Comment: Yout beat me by 4 mins @pickypg

Comment: @Archer Then i believe it would be better to add this conditions to the question. So people can keep it in mind before answering.

Answer (score 1):

What you apparently left out of your requirements statement is where "any number of characters" is supposed to end. As it stands, it ends at the end of the string; from your sample output, it seems you want it to end at the first space.

Try this pattern: `"\\d+,[^\\s]*"`