# Java Parsing outputted message

Tags: java, string, parsing

I need to parse this into strings in the most efficient way. I currently have this line

```
D[date-string] T[time-string] N[name-string] M[message-string]
```

Needs to be parsed into four strings respectively,

```
private String time; //would equal time-string
private String date; //would equal date-string
private String name; //would equal name-string
private String message; //would equal message-string
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: If you have a standard format for date, time, name & message then you can probably use regex and use `split` method in String class

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex and groups to match and extract that kind of data:
For example, something like:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("D(\\w+) T(\\w+) N(\\w+) M(\\w+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(yourString);
    if (m.matches()){
        String d = m.group(1);
        String t = m.group(2);
        String n = m.group(3);
        String w = m.group(4);
    }
```

The patterns within the parentheses are saved into groups, which you can extract after the match (it starts with 1, since 0 is the whole match).
You have then to change that to the characters and patterns you want to accept.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've understood you but looks like using regular expression is the easiest way to do this kind of parsing.

Comment: Seems to be the way to go. I just need to design one thats all.

Comment: I think this will work
D\[(.*?)]| T\[(.*?)]|N\[(.*?)]|M\[(.*?)]

Answer (score 0):

The below logic will work. How regix will hep not sure. But the below code will also be ok as it is not looping and anything so i think it will could be the optimum solution.

```
String s = "D[date-string] T[time-string] N[name-string] M[message-string]";   
String[] str = s.split(" ");    
 String date = str[0].substring(str[0].indexOf("[")+1, str[0].lastIndexOf("]")); //would equal time-string
 String time=str[1].substring(str[1].indexOf("[")+1, str[1].lastIndexOf("]")); //would equal date-string
 String name=str[2].substring(str[2].indexOf("[")+1, str[2].lastIndexOf("]")); //would equal name-string
 String message=str[3].substring(str[3].indexOf("[")+1, str[3].lastIndexOf("]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662215/how-to-extract-a-substring-using-regex) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726566/how-do-i-find-multiple-substrings-from-one-string-using-regex-in-java), you will have to tune it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, easy easy easy!

D[(.*?)] for the date!

https://regex101.com/r/vM0yW8/1